# Accepting answers?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

I've noticed that there are 96 questions at time of writing but only a handful it seems have accepted answers. Is this a problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not really: it's generally good practice to wait a few hours (or even a day or so) to allow others a chance to answer the question. We've only been open for just under a day.

If after a week or so people are still not accepting answers, then it's a problem that should probably be addressed by encouraging people in the comments to accept answers.

Comment: Agreed, I generally wait a few days as often it takes that long for me to implement a solution to the problem, test it and then give feedback as to whether it was the correct solution.

Comment: That makes sense. We will have to keep an eye on it.

Answer (score 1):

An even bigger issue is, what to do when multiple answers are correct?

For example, [How to remove the default “Anonymous” from comment author name?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/256/how-to-remove-the-default-anonymous-from-comment-author-name)

Both the answers to this question are valid. Which one do you vote for?
And only one of these can be accepted as an answer.

Comment: Always accept the answer that [helped you, personally, the most](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Comment: Having been in that situation myself - [adding CSS to a node/panel](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/126/any-way-to-add-css-for-a-single-page-node-esp-for-panel) - there was a most helpful answer, but another answer also helped, leaving comments and editing my question seemed like the way to go. Upvoting both answers might be another good way to go.

Answer (score 1):

There is no timeout for accepting an answer; the more you wait, the more answers you get.
It is also possible that the more correct answer is given 4 days after you ask your question.

Then, the fact there are answers doesn't mean one of them is correct, or acceptable.

Suppose, for example, that you ask a question about which code you should use to do a specific task (when you know which code you would use for Drupal 6, but you don't know which code you should use for Drupal 7), and where the answers are:

1. It is not possible.
2. It is possible, but using a PHP function.

Which answer would you select?